# How to find the element from the HTML provided through Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Actually this button is located inside container. Please provide syntax for **python**
Here this property has unique name, but dont know how to use this `[data-control-name="job_search_category_suggestion_it"]`

```
<button class="jobs-search-category-suggestions__button button-secondary-medium-muted mb2 mr2" data-control-name="job_search_category_suggestion_it" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-8126="8126">
    <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="search-icon" size="small"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="artdeco-icon" focusable="false"><path d="M14,12.67L11.13,9.8A5,5,0,1,0,9.8,11.13L12.67,14ZM3.88,7A3.13,3.13,0,1,1,7,10.13,3.13,3.13,0,0,1,3.88,7Z" class="small-icon" style="fill-opacity: 1"></path></svg></li-icon>IT
  </button>
```

I used this code:

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@data-control-name="job_search_category_suggestion_it]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the desired element is dynamic, so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='jobs-search-category-suggestions__button button-secondary-medium-muted mb2 mr2'][contains(.,'IT')]"))).click()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```